# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find : $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n})$ .

**My Approach:**

Let $x_n=(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n})$ .

I know that $\gamma_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n} -\log(n)$ . And $<\gamma_n>$ converges to Euler's constant i.e. $\gamma$ which lies between $0.3$ and $1$ .

Using this fact I found ,

$x_n=1+\gamma_{2n-1}+\log(2n-1)-\gamma_{2n}-\log(2n)$

since $\gamma_{2n-1}$ and $\gamma_{2n}$ are subsequences of convergent sequence $<\gamma_n>$ , so they converges to same limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ .

Hence , $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n= 1$ .

**Question:**

To check whether I'm wrong or right . Actually I don't have answers , Please help!

**EDIT:**
$(1)$ My approach is wrong.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor expansion of $\ln (1+x)$?

Comment: Your approach is correct, the fact you found is incorrect, but you are somewhat close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question of what you did wrong in your approach specifically, it's just that your arithmetic is wrong. You write (essentially) $x_n=1+\gamma_{2n-1}+\log(2n-1)-\left(\gamma_{2n}+\log(2n)\right)$; your idea of writing $x_n$ as a difference of harmonic terms is broadly correct, but let's look at what's going on here.  I'll write (using your notation) $H_n=\gamma_n+\log(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$ for the harmonic numbers; then what you've written is $1+H_{2n-1}-H_{2n}$.  But almost all of the terms cancel out of this sum, because it's not the case that $H_{2n-1}=1+\frac13+\frac15+\ldots+\frac1{2n-1}$ and $H_{2n}=\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n}$; instead, $H_{2n-1}=1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots$ and similarly for $H_{2n}$, so what you've written is just $1-\frac1{2n}$.

Instead, to use the approach you're trying, you need to start with $1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n}$ and then subtract the even terms *twice* :once to 'eliminate' them from the harmonic sum, yielding $1+\frac13+\frac15+\ldots$, and then a second time to 'add' the negative terms and give the sum $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots$ that you want.  This means that your sum is $$\begin{eqnarray}
1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n}-2(\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n}) \\ =1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1{2n}-(\frac22+\frac24+\frac26+\ldots+\frac2{2n}) \\ =1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1{2n}-(1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1n) \\
=H_{2n}-H_n
\end{eqnarray}$$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: , thanks sir! , yes I can finish from here.

Comment: sir ! , I've one doubt , Is the sum of series and it's limit equal , here  or always ?

Comment: @Abhishek That's an excellent question! You should always be careful about manipulating infinite series because it's easy to go wrong when you do. (For instance, imagine $1+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14+\ldots$ : this series is just a rearrangement of the terms in the one you've given, but it _doesn't_ converge; it's worth figuring out why!) But note that all the manipulations that have been done here were done on _finite_ series, and those manipulations are always valid. The only limit is taken after the arithmetic has been done.

Comment: The only catch is that you should convince yourself that (to use your notation) $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\gamma_{2n}-\gamma_n)=0$, and _why_ it's zero; you might find the classical definition of limit useful for that. (Note that all you'll need for that is that $\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n$ exists, not its definition or its value.)

Comment: ,Thanks again sir ! , now I understood that we can rearrange the terms of a series if it is finite .And $\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_{2n}-\gamma_n=0$ ,because $<\gamma_n>$ is a convergent sequence and $<\gamma_{2n}>$ is it's subsequence , so it'll converge to same limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Taylor expansion for $\log (x+1)$ around 0 is $$x-x^2/2+x^3/3-\cdots = \sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is actually correct, you made a mistake in the computations:

Note that
$$x_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n}= \left( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-2 \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\\=\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)- \left( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\=\gamma_{2n} +\ln(2n)-\gamma_n-\ln(x)=\gamma_{2n}-\gamma_n+\ln(2)$$

**Alternate solution** The following is a classical alternate sulution:

Prove by induction the (well known identity):

$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n}= \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$$
and identify the RHS as a Riemann sum.