# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \big[\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{n\cdot(2n+1)}\big]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg[\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{n\cdot(2n+1)}\bigg]$ .

This is a similar question as I've asked an hour ago . [Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...-\frac{1}{2n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626803/find-lim-n-to-infty-1-frac12-frac13-frac12n)

But here, I am not able to rearrange terms to use the fact that $\gamma_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n} -\log(n)$ .

Any ideas ? Or Is there any other way to find limit?

Comment: Please use `\cdot` instead of `.` for multiplication; otherwise it would make $1\cdot3$, $2\cdot5$ look like decimals.

Comment: $\frac1{n(2n+1)}=2\left[\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right]$.

Comment: Maple says, $2- \ln4$

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5Ccdot(2n%2B1)%7D%24&p=1) you can find [this question]([How to find sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n(2n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334870))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that $\frac1{n(2n+1)}=2\left[\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right]$ to reduce the problem to that of finding $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots$ This is a classical series, that adds up to $\ln 2$. (You can see this by considering the power series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and evaluating at $x=1$ using Abel's theorem. There are other ways.) I'll leave to you the easy algebra that gives the value you need from this series.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm posting this answer to help other users.

Finally, As Martin Sleziak sir stated in chat and Andrés E. Caicedo hinted  in his answer ,

$T_n=\frac1{n(2n+1)}=2\left[\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right]$ .

We can relate the limit of this sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ with the partial sum of $n$ terms of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty   2\left[\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right]$ . And as $n\to \infty$ , the series sums to [$2-\ln(4)$] , which is equal to our limit.